# the value of undo_sql in flashback_transaction_query view is always null

Tags: oracle, flashback

so I have a table defined as follow:

```
`create table test.test as (select * from dual);
```

and ran the following update statements:

```
update test.test set dummy = '1' where dummy = 'X';
commit;
```

I want to find the undo_sql for the transaction above, so I ran the following statement to find the transaction id

```
SQL> select dummy, versions_xid, versions_startscn, versions_endscn from test.test
versions between scn minvalue and maxvalue ;

D VERSIONS_XID     VERSIONS_STARTSCN VERSIONS_ENDSCN
- ---------------- ----------------- ---------------
1 0A000500B00A0000           2802291
X                                            2802291
```

and ran the following statement to find the undo_sql statement

```
SQL> select undo_sql from flashback_transaction_query 
where xid = (select  versions_xid from test.test versions 
between scn minvalue and maxvalue where versions_xid is not null);

UNDO_SQL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

as you can see, I got nothing, if I run the following statement, I also get nothing.

```
SQL> select undo_sql from flashback_transaction_query where undo_sql is not null;

no row selected
```

looks like undo_sql is always null;

Is there anything I didn't configure ?  Here are the values from v$system_parameter

```
SQL> select name, value from v$system_parameter where name like '%undo%';

NAME                 VALUE
----------------     ----------------
undo_management      AUTO
undo_tablespace      UNDOTBS1
undo_retention       18000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I remember, you should have supplemental logging be enabled so that database can collect the data needed to reconstruct the undo statements used for Flashback Transaction Query:

```
ALTER DATABASE ADD SUPPLEMENTAL LOG DATA;
```

For more information on enabling supplemental logging, read ["Configuring Your Database for Oracle Flashback Transaction Query"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25518/adfns_flashback.htm#BJFGJHCJ) section in Advanced Application Developer's Guide and ["Supplemental Logging"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/logminer.htm#SUTIL1582) section in Database Utilities (LogMiner is another utility which depends on supplemental logging).